# Retrieve last 10 results ASC Left Join MySql

Tags: mysql, left-join

I'm trying to retrieve the last 10 posts from a `posts` table ordered ASC, but the last left joined query doesn't retrieve anything.

**Basic**: it retrieves results ordered DESC

```
SELECT 
    p.post, p.id_post, u.name
FROM 
    posts p
LEFT JOIN 
    users u ON u.id_user = p.id_user
WHERE 
    p.id_user = 4 
ORDER BY 
    p.date  DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

**Ordered ASC**: it doesn't work at all:

```
SELECT 
    num.* 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         p.post, p.id_post, u.name
     FROM 
         posts p
     LEFT JOIN 
         users u ON u.id_user = p.id_user
     WHERE 
         p.id_user = 4 
     ORDER BY 
         p.date DESC 
     LIMIT 10) num 
ORDER BY 
    p.date ASC
```

What am I doing wrong?

In my php variables I use `$row['id_post']` `$row['post']` `$row['name']`. I don't want to use `array_reverse()` just plain `sql`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the date in the subquery:

```
SELECT pu.post, pu.id_post, pu.name
FROM (SELECT p.*, u.name
      FROM posts p LEFT JOIN
           users u
           ON u.id_user = p.id_user
      WHERE p.id_user = 4 
      ORDER BY p.date DESC 
      LIMIT 10
     ) pu 
ORDER BY pu.date ASC;
```

Your second query should have returned an error message to the effect that `date` is not recognized as a column.  You should be capturing *and reading* error messages, if you want to write an effective application.

Comment: Yes the second query returned error I set it up with `die();`. Your answer solved my question, thank you!.